"Angular Firebase: User ID is null and localStorage Unavailable in SSR with isPlatformBrowser"
dashboard.component.ts :
  ngOnInit() {
    const userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    if (userId) {
      this.loadProfileImage(userId);
    } else {
      console.error('User ID is null. Cannot load profile image.');
    }
  }

  

auth.service.ts :
getUserId(): string | null {
    const user = this.firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    return user ? user.uid : null;
  }

terminal errors/messages :
User ID is null. Cannot load profile image.
localStorage is not available

whenever i run "ng serve" , those terminal errors/messages appears , and I guess they're the reason why I have a problem in updating users' profile pics , the problem is mainly in getUserId method in authservice ig

please share how you are importing firebaseAuth also please share the github repo

yes when you run SSR (Server side rendering) you can not access localstorage which is located in the browser. Localstorage is (probably) used by this.authService.getUserId() to retrieve which user is logged in. since this can not be done on the server site, you need to omit this code, this can be done by isPlatformBrowser().
In your code you first need to add platformId to your constructor
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string)

When use isPlatformBrowser to make sure that the affected code only runs in the browser and not on the server side.
  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))
    {
      const userId = this.authService.getUserId();
      if (userId) {
        this.loadProfileImage(userId);
      } else {
        console.error('User ID is null. Cannot load profile image.');
      }
    }
  }

below are the imports you need todo
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';


I already have this : constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: string).
well , now in terminal the only error that still appears is : localStorage is not available
but in dev tools , this error keeps appearing even if I'm logging in : "User ID is null. Cannot load profile image",
I guess that the problem is in getUserId in authservice
